# Parallel paypal Payment Not Working

Tags: php, paypal

I am working in project In that I need to integrate Adaptive payment gateway. I referred code from [here](http://www.formget.com/paypal-parallel-payments/) , it looks simple and easy but once I downloaded and run the code its not working

The problem I found is.. In the process page the variable `$ack` is returning failure

How can I resolve this problem

Here is the sample code

**Process.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../PPBootStrap.php');
    require_once('../Common/Constants.php');
    define("DEFAULT_SELECT", "- Select -");
    $returnUrl = "http://www.formget.com/tutorial/paypal-adaptive-    payment/parallel/success.php";
    $cancelUrl = "http://www.formget.com/tutorial/paypal-adaptive-    payment/parallel/index.php";
    $memo = "Adaptive Payment";
    $actionType = "PAY";
    $currencyCode = "USD";

    if ($_POST['booking'] == 'f') {
        $receiverEmail = array("airline@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("300.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("AirGo Airline's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'h') {
        $receiverEmail = array("hotel@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("200.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("Hotel TheCompany's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'c') {
        $receiverEmail = array("car-merchants@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("100.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("MyCar Car Company's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'fh') {
        $receiverEmail = array("airline@outlook.com", "hotel@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("300.00", "200.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false", "false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("AirGo Airline's Test Store", "Hotel     TheCompany's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'fc') {
        $receiverEmail = array("airline@outlook.com", "car-merchants@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("300.00", "100.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false", "false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("AirGo Airline's Test Store", "MyCar     Car Company's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'hc') {
        $receiverEmail = array("hotel@outlook.com", "car-merchants@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("200.00", "100.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false", "false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("Hotel TheCompany's Test Store",     "MyCar Car Company's Test Store");
    } elseif ($_POST['booking'] == 'fhc') {
        $receiverEmail = array("airline@outlook.com", "hotel@outlook.com", "car-merchants@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("295.00", "195.00", "95.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false", "false", "false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("AirGo Airline's Test Store", "Hotel     TheCompany's Test Store", "MyCar Car Company's Test Store");
    } else {
        $receiverEmail = array("airline@outlook.com");
        $receiverAmount = array("300.00");
        $primaryReceiver = array("false");
        $_SESSION['facilty_provider'] = array("AirGo Airline's Test Store");
    }
    if (isset($receiverEmail)) {
        $receiver = array();
        /*
         * A receiver's email address
        */
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($receiverEmail); $i++) {
        $receiver[$i] = new Receiver();
        $receiver[$i]->email = $receiverEmail[$i];
        /*
        * Amount to be credited to the receiver's account
        */
        $receiver[$i]->amount = $receiverAmount[$i];
        /*
        * Set to true to indicate a chained payment; only one receiver can be a     primary receiver. Omit this field, or set it to false for simple and parallel     payments.
        */
        $receiver[$i]->primary = $primaryReceiver[$i];
    }
        $receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
}
$payRequest = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), $actionType, $cancelUrl, $currencyCode, $receiverList, $returnUrl);
// Add optional params
if ($memo != "") {
    $payRequest->memo = $memo;
}
/*
* ## Creating service wrapper object
Creating service wrapper object to make API call and loading
Configuration::getAcctAndConfig() returns array that contains credential and     config parameters
*/


$service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {
    /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
    $response = $service->Pay($payRequest);
    echo $ack = strtoupper($response->responseEnvelope->ack);
    if ($ack == "SUCCESS") {
        $_SESSION['pay_key'] = $payKey = $response->payKey;
        $payKey = $response->payKey;
        $payPalURL = PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL . '_ap-payment&paykey=' . $payKey;
        header('Location: ' . $payPalURL);
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    require_once '../Common/Error.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to indent your code as it's very hard to be understood..  It will help you too in the future, if there is any change you need to do..

Comment: what are the error code that you get from the response? Mind to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problems here, the issue was in you configuration file. There is a variable of acct1.AppId. By default, the creator of this sample code has comment it so you are sending a request without including the App ID. To solve this, you should uncomment it. Try to run again after that.

[image]